# from numeric value to time value

Tags: sas

I want to convert numeric data to time variable. I have a column with values such as 415, 515, 1487, 1467 . 
I want to convert these values into a format of 04:15, 05:15, 14:87 and so on.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyF7K.jpg)
 Afterwards I want to extract hours and minutes out of them in separate columns such as 04 in 1st column and 15 in another column”

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. Did the concepts of modulus 100 and division by 100 escape you?

Comment: data Q1; 
set P1;

format sched_dep_time z4.;

sched_dep_time=put(sched_dep_time,4.);
sched_dep_time=substr(sched_dep_time,1,2);


run;

Comment: I am not getting how to do it? Could you please help.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Additional information for a question should go in an edit of the question.  Placing new info in a comment breaks up the question and can make things hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion could be done in one line when using PUT and INPUT together. Than extract hours and minutes.

```
data have;
  do time_as_encoded_number = 415, 515, 1487, 1467, 1022, 1215, 2345;
    output;
  end;
run;
data want;
  set have;
  format time_as_SAS_time time5.;
  time_as_SAS_time=input(put(time_as_encoded_number,z4.),hhmmss4.);
  hour=HOUR(time_as_SAS_time);
  minute=MINUTE(time_as_SAS_time);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Z4` in a `format` statement specifies how the value is displayed, not how it is treated as data.  The `4.` in a `put` function call specifies how the numeric value is converted to a character representation of the number.  In SAS, unlike in scripting languages, a variable's type is static during the data step and when saved in an output data set.  Best practice is the conceptually 'give' `sched_dep_time` a 'role (or type) and stick with it, creating new variables for the other roles of hour, minute and SAS time.

```
data have;
  input time_as_encoded_number;
datalines;
415
1022
1215
2345
run;

data want;
  set have;
  hour = floor(time_as_encoded_number / 100);
  minute = mod(time_as_encoded_number , 100);
  time_as_SAS_time = DHMS(0,hour,minute,0);
  format time_as_SAS_time time5.;

  * for demonstration only, causes a NOTE, and goes in circle Num->Char->Num;
  length x 8;
  x = put (time_as_encoded_number,4.);

run;
```

Note: A statement such as the demonstration 'works' with a `NOTE:` because it is going in circles.  A number is being converted to a character by `put` and implicitly converted back to number due to left hand side  = right hand side .

```
length x 8;
x = put (time_as_encoded_number,4.);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show actual source data that replicates the problem, including any errors that you're seeing. I'll assume that you have a numeric variable called `sched_dep_time`, and that you want to get the hours and minutes values into two additional numeric variables. As Richard suggests, you can use [modulo arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to do this:

```
data want;
  set have;
  * Get the integer number of hours by dividing by 100;
  hours = int(sched_dep_time / 100);
  * Get the number of minutes by getting the remainder after dividing by 100;
  minutes = mod(sched_dep_time, 100);
run;
```